# JavaScript remove string from list on click if already exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having issues with adding and removing items from my list on click. The removal function works only once.

HTML

```
<h1 id="show-list></h1>
<ul id="my-list>
    <li data-itemname="C1">C1</li>
    <li data-itemname="B23">B23</li>
    <li data-itemname="D52">D54</li>
   ...
```

JS

```
$('#my-list').each(function() {

var $widget = $(this),
    $itemname = $(this).attr('data-itemname'),
    ...

$widget.on('click', function() {

  $currentlist = document.getElementById('show-list').innerHTML;
  // create current list array
  var str = $currentlist; // C1, B23, D54, etc
  var array = str.split(',');
  // convert item number to string
  var itemtocheck = $itemname.toString(); // works OK
  // check if value in array
  var result = $.inArray(itemtocheck, array); // so far so good

  if (result == 0) {
    selecteditems = $currentlist.replace(itemtoremove+',', ''); 
    $('#show-list').html(selecteditems); // Works only once
    return false;
  } else {
    $('#show-list').append($itemname+','); // will add OK
    return false;
  }
});

...
```

Also I feel that this function can be simplified?

Comment: You must to set Id to each item list.

Comment: $("item id").remove;

Comment: Please show a full example, that makes the problem reproducible - yours doesn't, f.e. what `$itemname` is supposed to be or where it comes from, is totally unclear. Please go read [mcve].

Comment: As per request, I have added additional info. Thanks for looking!

Comment: If you remove the last item doesn't work because you search `itemtoremove + ","` and the last element (I suppose) do not have comma. Why you remove the string instead of remove (slice) the `array` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Rewrote it

```
var $showList = $('#show-list');
$('#my-list').find('li').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var itemName = $this.data('itemname');

    var showListText = $showList.text();
    var showListItems = showListText.split(',');
    var itemIndex = showListItems.indexOf(itemName);

    if (itemIndex > -1) {
        // remove item
        showListItems.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    } else {
        // append item
        showListItems.push(itemName);
    }

    showListText = showListItems.filter(function (a) { return !!a; }).join(',');
    $showList.text(showListText);
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvmm569x/7)

EDIT 3:
Just from a best practices stand point I prefix jQuery objects with `$` and nothing else. I feel like it makes the code much more readable and allows you to give a variable a "type" so you always know what's what.

Comment: Thanks. Take your time. Pretty much all this does is a visual display of what items have been selected.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the help! Much appreciated!

Comment: @WayBehind no problem, check out [Airbnb's style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/README.md). You'll definitely pick up a couple tricks reading it all the way though and if you follow it in your day to day you will end up writing better code.

Comment: All great! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are needing?  I'd skip converting to an array first.  Also, what's $itemname in your code?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function removeItemFromList(listName, itemName) {
                var selectobject=document.getElementById(listName);
                for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++){
                    if (selectobject.options[i].value == itemName) {
                        selectobject.remove(i);
                    }
                }
            }

            function addItemToList(listName, itemName, itemValue) {
                var selectobject=document.getElementById(listName);
                var found = false;
                for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++){
                    if (selectobject.options[i].value == itemValue) {
                        found = true;
                        // already in list, don't re-add
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!found) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = itemName;
                    option.value = itemValue;
                    selectobject.add(option);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="show-list">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="remove volvo" onclick="removeItemFromList('show-list', 'volvo');"  />
        <input type="button" value="remove saab" onclick="removeItemFromList('show-list', 'saab');"  />
        <input type="button" value="add delorean" onclick="addItemToList('show-list', 'DeLorean', 'delorean');"  />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have updated the original post. the item name is from this `<li data-itemname="C1">C1</li>`